# How do I test a standlone script file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pytest

I've written a module to be installed via pip with a dir structure like:

```
bin/myapp
src/mymodule
src/mymodule/__init__.py
src/mymodule/config.py
src/mymodule/file1.py
src/mymodule/file2.py
tests/func/
tests/unit/file1/test_func1.py
tests/unit/file1/test_func2.py
tests/unit/file2/test_func1.py
setup.py
setup.cfg
```

setup.py contains:

```
scripts=['bin/myapp'],
```

myapp imports mymodule and is the "wrapper" script that executes the module code as needed. e.g. myapp contains:

```
import mymodule

def main(config_file):
    mymodule.read_config(config_file)
    ...
    mymodule.do_something_else
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ...
    main(config_file)
```

I want to write a test under 'func/' (func/test_myapp.py) that will setup a directory structure and then execute "myapp" which calls my module for an end to end test (I will need to mock some functions as they do call real executables that wont exist on a test machine).

But I cant seem to find a good article that tells me how to import 'bin/myapp' so that it can be tested.

Any help is appreciated.

P.S. Code example must be compatible with both 2.7 and 3.x hence both are tagged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of putting logic in `bin/myapp`, put one or more functions in `mymodule/cli.py` and use an entrypoint: https://packaging.python.org/specifications/entry-points/

You'll minimize the boilerplate you write and the logic will be importable in your tests and for anyone else who installs the package - you may find it more convenient to call the function directly in some cases than shell out if you want more explicit control in other clients.

Your exact question of testing is addressed here as well: http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command-line-scripts.html#the-console-scripts-entry-point

Answer (score 1):

one way to do it might be to `subprocess` the bin in the test, and then test each expected item after the bin is done executing. so like in test_func1.py

something like

```
import subprocess
def test1():
    stdout = subprocess.check_output(['bin/myapp'])
    assert os.listdir('./newfolder') == ['blah1', 'blah2']
    assert stdout == '''some expected output'''
```

has the benefit of being closer to an integration test, but also has the downside of actually being closer to an integration test so might need to clean after testing.

or you can:

```
def test1():
    from myapp import main
    assert main()
```